# findAllBy JPA with embeddedId

Tags: kotlin, spring-data-jpa, jpql, composite-primary-key, hibernate-jpa

I have this `Document` hibernate jpa entity with an `EmbeddedId`:

```
@Entity
data class Document(
        @EmbeddedId
        @NotNull
        val documentExpertId: DocumentExpertId,
        // other fields
)

@Embeddable
data class DocumentExpertId(

        @Column(nullable = false)
        val expertId: String,

        @Column(nullable = false)
        val name: String

) : Serializable
```

To get all the documents by `expertId`, I would like to have my document JPA repository interface method called:

`fun findAllByExpertId(String expertId): List<Document>`

But, the only way I found to do so is:

`fun findAllByDocumentExpertIdExpertId(String expertId): List<Document>`

Is there an other way to have a better name for this method?

Answer (score 0):

You could change the ID and column definition to:

```
    @EmbeddedId
    @NotNull
    val documentExpertKey: DocumentExpertKey,

    @Column(name = "expertId", nullable = false)
    val id: String,
```

So that your query could be:

```
    fun findAllByDocumentExpertKeyId(String expertId): List<Document>
```

That looks a little more normal to me.

Comment: I don't really want to add a @Column just for naming and neither set a label "id" for "expertId"...

Comment: You wouldn't be adding a new `@Column` in. You'd modify what you have. `Spring Data JPA`  by default will associate the variable name with the column name, but you can name the variable name whatever you want and that's what `Spring Data JPA` will use for the dervied queries. Hopefully that makes sense